# How to plot both x function and y function in one plane with Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two functions:

`y = x - x^3`and 
`x = y^3 - y`
I need to plot them both in one plane, I wonder how to achieve this with Mathematica?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? people respond better if you show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `ContourPlot`

let's Wrap it in Manipulate to make it more easy to adjust

```
 Manipulate[

 With[{f1 = y == x - x^3, f2 = x == y^3 - y},
  ContourPlot[{f1, f2}, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {{y, None}, {x, {f1, f2}}},
   ImagePadding -> 30,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.001], LightGray]]
  ],

 {{lim, 3, "limit"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]